# Having trouble starting a new line with \mbox

Tags: line-breaking

Here is what I've tried so far

```
\[\mbox{
\Large$
(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2+
\\
(-2)1+0(1)+(1)3+
\\
1(2)+(-1)(1)+0(4)
$}
\]
```

However, `\\` is not working here. Can any genius get this done?

**The reason why I use `\mbox` is that I want  a relatively large font size.**

Comment: Remove the \mbox and the $$ and move the \Large outside the `\[..\]`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How can you maintain the font size at the same time?

Comment: Add braces to get a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible working examples:

1) With `align` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{Large}
\begin{align*}
&(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2+{}\\
&(-2)1+0(1)+(1)3+{}\\
&1(2)+(-1)(1)+0(4)
\end{align*}
\end{Large}
\end{document}
```

2) With `gather` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{Large}
\begin{gather*}
(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2+{}\\
(-2)1+0(1)+(1)3+{}\\
1(2)+(-1)(1)+0(4)
\end{gather*}
\end{Large}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to use larger (or smaller) font size in the display, you need to change size *inside* the display, which can be done using a `minipage`. You're maybe asking why: the answer is in the first example in the picture below. Both hair-splitter's and Steven's answers suffer from the issue, namely that the part of the paragraph before the display is typeset with the wrong baseline skip.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newenvironment{faligned}[1][\Large]
 {\begin{minipage}{\displaywidth}#1\[\begin{aligned}}
 {\end{aligned}\]\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\section{This doesn't really work}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{Large}
\begin{align*}
&(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2+{}\\
&(-2)1+0(1)+(1)3+{}\\
&1(2)+(-1)(1)+0(4)
\end{align*}
\end{Large}
\lipsum[2][1-2]

\section{This does}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\[
\begin{faligned}
&(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2+{}\\
&(-2)1+0(1)+(1)3+{}\\
&1(2)+(-1)(1)+0(4)
\end{faligned}
\]
\lipsum[2][1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `faligned` environment has an optional argument so you can also say

```latex
\begin{faligned}[\Huge]
...
\end{faligned}
```

to get very large size.

Comment: Another drawback of the `Large` pseudo-environment is the spurious space following it...

Answer (score 2):

REVISED ANSWER: Here, I tweak some macros of `tabstackengine` to place the contents of the TABstack cells in `\Large` prior to being set in math mode.  I accomplish this by introducing an optional argument for `\TABstackMathstyle` in which the optional argument is executed *prior* to entering math mode for typesetting the cell contents.

In this way, the `\baselineskip` of paragraph typesetting is unaffected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\makeatletter
\def\TAB@mathPREstyle{}
\renewcommand\TABstackMathstyle[2][]{\renewcommand\TAB@mathstyle{#2}%
  \renewcommand\TAB@mathPREstyle{#1}}

\renewcommand\TABstackMath{\renewcommand\TAB@delim[1]{\TAB@mathPREstyle%
  \ensuremath{\TAB@mathstyle##1}}\let\recent@TAB@delim\TAB@delim}
\makeatother
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle[\Large]{}% <--NEW SYNTAX WITH OPTIONAL PRE-MATH SETTING
\setstackgap{L}{1.6\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
This is the line before This is the line before
This is the line before This is the line before
This is the line before This is the line before
This is the line before This is the line before
This is the line before
\[
\tabbedCenterstack[l]{
(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2+
\\
(-2)1+0(1)+(1)3+
\\
1(2)+(-1)(1)+0(4)
}
\]
This is the line afterward This is the line afterward
This is the line afterward This is the line afterward
This is the line afterward This is the line afterward
This is the line afterward This is the line afterward
This is the line afterward This is the line afterward
This is the line afterward
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Original answer EDITED to [attempt to] correct the improper spacing issues cited by egreg.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\begin{document}
%\parskip 20pt
This is the line before This is the line before
This is the line before This is the line before
This is the line before This is the line before
This is the line before This is the line before
This is the line before
\begingroup\par\vspace{-\parskip}\Large
\[
\Vectorstack[l]{
(1)(1)+2(1)+(-1)2+
\\
(-2)1+0(1)+(1)3+
\\
1(2)+(-1)(1)+0(4)
}
\]\endgroup
This is the line afterward This is the line afterward
This is the line afterward This is the line afterward
This is the line afterward This is the line afterward
This is the line afterward This is the line afterward
This is the line afterward This is the line afterward
This is the line afterward
\end{document}
```

[image]